# Django: Select where sum of columns equals some constant

Tags: python, sql, django, django-orm

I've searched the docs and I can't find a simple way to run a query like this:

```
SELECT columns FROM table WHERE col_a + col_b = @param
```

I know I can use `.extra(where=['col_a + col_b = %s' % whatever])`, but this is not parameterized.

Is there a way to do this in the ORM (i.e. without `extra`)? Otherwise, what's the cleanest way of running that query?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to filter with F() expressions.
See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model

Try this:

```
from django.db.models import F
Something.objects.filter(col_a=CONST-F('col_b'))
```

Haven't tried it but it might work like this: If CONST = 10 and if column B is for example 8, then fetch only if the column A is 2.

Comment: Yeah I thought of this. I find it pretty hard to read though and it gets worse if my expression is more complex (since it has to be completely rearranged). Still it might be the best solution.